# strong induction postage question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Use strong Principle of induction to prove that the amount of postage greater than or equal to $30$ cents can be made  using a combination of $10$ cent and $3$ cent postage

this is what i have so far:
Proof: let $r(n) : n=3p +10q, p,q \in \mathbb{N},n>0$

Base case $n=30,31,32$

$n=30, 3(10) + 10(0)..p(30)$ is true

$n=31, 3(7) + 10(1)..p(31)$ is true

$n=32, 3(4) + 10(1)..p$ is true

Assume $p(k)$ is true for up to $k\geq 32$

$k\geq 32$

$\Rightarrow k+1\geq 33$

$\Rightarrow(k+1)-3\geq 30$

$\Rightarrow k-2=30$

Comment: Assume statement is true for $k$ and then prove for $k+3$.

Comment: would it be k-2 +3 = 3p+10q +3...then id end up with k+1=3(p+1) +10 q??....is that correct? this last step is giving me problems

Comment: So you are saying you assumed $p(k-2)$ is true and then wish to prove $p(k+1)$ is true?

Comment: yeah. does that make any sense? i dont know..saw this method online

Comment: Yes, it is fine.

Comment: so to confirm..the solution looks ok?

Comment: By the way, the statement holds for $n\ge 18$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have proved the base cases $k = 30, 31$ and $32$. Assume $p(k)$ is true for some $k\in\mathbb N$, so let $k = 3p + 10q$, $p,q\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$.

For $n = k+3$,

$$k+3 = 3p+10q+3 = 3(p+1) + 10q$$

Since $p\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$, $(p+1)\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$. So $p(n)$ is true by the principle of mathematical induction for integers $n\ge 30$.