# need to know if this is correct

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Use strong Principle of induction to prove that the amount of postage greater than or equal to 8cents cents can be made using a combination of 3 cent and 5 cent postage

this is what i have so far: Proof: let r(n):n=3p+5q,p,q∈N,n>0
Base case n=8,9,10
n=8,3(1)+5(1)..p(8) is true

n=9,3(3)+5(0)..p(9) is true

n=10,3(0)+10(1)..p is true

Assume p(k) is true for up to k≥10
k≥32

⇒k+1≥10
⇒(k+1)−3≥11

⇒k−2=8

k-2=3p+5q

add 3 on both sides to get k+1

k+1=3p+5q+3

k+1= 3(p+1) +5q

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Isn't this just like your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055915/strong-induction-postage-question)?

Comment: yes..im practicing for an exam..and im not confident about these questions at all..sorry

Comment: The induction step is exactly like the one in your previous question: assume for $n=k$, prove for $n=k+3$.

Comment: @Timbuc If you have to post a link to a math formatting guide without even a clarification about what kind of link it is and why you've posted it, at least post the better (original) link: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Arthur, there is no official link to this, as there was some time before. I post what I know. The why is, imo, obvious.

Comment: @Timbuc While the why might be obvious once you click the link and can see what it contains, it is very bad form to post a link without clarifying what it links to (this goes for the internet in general, imo). Also, now you know, so there no reason to link to the meta.ME version. The original link is strictly better, since it contains a lot more secondary posts as answers.

Comment: I don't think it is bad *in this case*: I'm not asking anything. Besides this, as you can seem the posted has done nothing. About the "original link": how do you kinow that's **the** original one? And anyway: had the poster been interested he could have looked for something else. Apparently, he is not interested. It is a pity that we don't have a specific link in the site anymore for this: there was one some time ago.

Comment: @Timbuc I know it's the original one because the post you linked _says_ it's the original one. I agree that the guide (or something very like it) should be linked officially somewhere. As for clarifying a link as you post it, people should have the opportunity to judge whether they want to click the link, and they cannot do that if they only have the first fifty characters of the url to go by.